# how to initialize value inside run block in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

how to initialize value inside run block in angular.js

```
directives.value("value1","test1");

directives.run(function(value1){
    value1="test2";
})
```

Is this possible

Comment: Did this work for you?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a primitive as the value, you will only get a copy of that injected into the run function and you will not be able to replace the original one.

Use an object instead:

```
directives.value("value1", { something: "test1" });

directives.run(function(value1){
    value1.something = "test2";
})
```